# Excel - How Do I Keep Formula Ranges From Converting to #Ref When Invalid?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm automating an excel file with multiple database calls. While doing this I'm unintentionally breaking various areas of the spreadsheet that contain lookup formulas like below:

```
=INDEX('Schedule Details'!$B$3:$B500,MATCH("English Total",'Schedule Details'!$C$3:$C500,0))
```

After it breaks the function is being changed to this:

```
=INDEX('Schedule Details'!#REF!,MATCH("English Total",'Schedule Details'!#REF!,0))
```

I've read and understand that this happens because the range I'm pointing to is not valid, but what I don't understand is why it has to actually change the formula itself instead of just marking the call value as #REF!.

Is there a way to lock down the formula so that it cannot be changed?  I've tried going to Format Cells --> Protection --> Locked and it has no effect. It's getting really tiring to have to retype in the range everytime I make an adjustment to the spreadsheet :(

Comment: Debug your statements that attempt to fill in that `#REF` area part - something you're attempting to insert there "doesn't make sense" to Excel, in essence.  Is there a reason you DON'T want to force something to show you that you've broken it?  Your intended answer sounds like you want to ignore problems.

Comment: As a sidenote, I've done a lot of DB and Interop work with Excel.  It's possible that your previous work was moving/deleting the B rows temporarily, hence creating a "bad" range that isn't recognized later on.

Comment: You can make all your formulas text by using Replace to replace all the `=` with `'=` Then after you made all the changes to the data reverse it, then clean up the range references.

Comment: I'd also consider maybe creating a named range, so if you're updating a table rather than pasting new data where old data used to be the named references may still be active.

Comment: Would `=INDEX(INDEX('Schedule Details'!$B:$B,1):INDEX('Schedule Details'!$B:$B,500),MATCH("English Total",INDEX('Schedule Details'!$C:$C,3):INDEX('Schedule Details'!$C:$C,500),0)) ` work?  (it won't if column B or C gets completely deleted).

Comment: @gravity I'm not wanting to ignore problems, I simply don't understand why it would physically change the formula -- that's why I said I wish it'd show a cell value of "#REF!", that way I see there's an error and I could look at the formula to see which cells are getting referenced that are incorrect.  

Also these cells are referencing a table that's getting refreshed, so I'm going to try the idea of changing to a ranged reference...